# Code crashing when ran too frequently. Firebase / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func grabPosts2(){
    posts = []

    currentUserRef?.child("invitedToPosts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: cutoff).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                let postKey = snap.key
                DataService.ds.REF_INITIATIONS.child(postKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                        if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{

                            let post = Post(postKey: snapshot.key, postData: dict)
                            self.posts.append(post)


                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }    
                }) 
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Database example:

```
User
  invitedToPosts
       09283094823904
            timestamp: 30909000909

Initiations
       09283094823904
             post information
```

What the code above is doing is going into a user's invitedToPosts, if the timestamp is recent enough, grab the key and go find it in the Initiations, then grab out the post information, make a post object with it, append it to my posts array, and reload my tableview each time.

I run this code on startup and then I've got both a button and a refresh controller that runs this function.

If I slowly tap on the refresh button or do my drag to refresh slowly I never get a crash with this code. However, if I tap on the button super quickly, sometimes I can tap it 3 times and sometimes I can tap on it 20 times, but eventually the code crashes.

I'm getting an index out of range on this line in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 let post = posts[indexPath.row]
```

So I assume it's got something to do with clearing out the post array and trying to refresh the page while another request is running slowly and then it catches up and everything goes nuts. No idea though.

Any ideas how to safely run this code or how to successfully write this so that when I aim to refresh my tableview with up to date information I won't get this crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the DispatchQueue? Also, why are you refreshing the table every time a post is added to the array. It would probably be more efficient to populate the array, then reload the table once (minus the DispatchQueue).